# Return an instance of current subclass with function?

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

I've found that I'm repeating the same try/catch code inefficiently, so I'm wanting to provide a function to all my NSManagedObject subclasses, so that they can simply return an existing object of their type, if it exists. I'd like for this function to return an object of the relevant class, rather than just a NSManagedObject. So for example, if i were to call `DataMessage.existingObject(objectID: messageID)`, I would be getting a DataMessage back, as that's the class I've called it upon. And I don't need to do `as! DataMessage` every time.

Here's the code I have now, which isn't quite right:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func existingObject(objectID objectID: NSManagedObjectID, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self? {
        let message: NSManagedObject?

        do {
            message = try context.existingObjectWithID(objectID)
        }
        catch {
            message = nil
        }

        return message
    }
}
```

I seem to be almost there. How can I get it to return an instance of the class for which the function was called on?

Comment: Did you try casting the return object to the desired type? Or did you maybe use the `is` keyword to check what subclass `message` is to return that subclass.

Comment: Why are you extending NSManagedObjectContext and not NSManagedObject?

Comment: There are a number of questions on SO that talk about creating a new instance of a dynamic type and all of them suggest you need to use some Objective-C to do so.

Comment: @jtbandes mistake. edited.

Comment: Hey Andrew, consider this QA ... notice the absolutely amazing answer (the final one in the answer) which, incredibly, can both infer and take a type.  I'm not sure I totally follow your question but could that technique be the solution here?

Comment: You can do it as long as you mark your NSManagedObject subclass `final` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287283/all-classes-conforming-to-protocol-inherit-default-implementation/38287557#38287557